# React Native: How to disable scrolling in ListView?

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to disable scrolling of ListView? I've tried `noScroll`:

```
<ListView noScroll={true}>
</ListView>
```

But it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Would be nice to actually solve this...

Comment: @GoreDefex check inheritance, already does

Answer (score 121, accepted):

i think it should be

```
scrollEnabled={false}
```

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#props

Comment: Why have so many people check marked this? This is wrong. ListView's do not allow you to change the scroll ability at all, Scroll View's do.

Comment: It works for ListView. The props get passed into the ScrollView which is the default.

Comment: Like @AndrewJM said, it inherits the proptypes: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/24d34fe203a341b678e00ab4316e8838c50d2be9/Libraries/CustomComponents/ListView/ListView.js#L130-L131

Comment: This worked for ListView, at least for me, react native 0.39

Comment: How do i disable it later, like in a particular page, i want to disable scrolling. This prop must be declared at the beginning, how do i change it after rendering?

Comment: @TomSawyer REFERENCE.setNativeProps({ scrollEnabled: truthy });

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes scrolling is disabled only by applying both `scrollEnabled` and `nestedScrollEnabled`:

```
<ScrollView
  scrollEnabled={false}
  nestedScrollEnabled={false}
>
  {children}
</ScrollView>
```